# Docker image got a latest tag

Tags: docker

I built an image and tagged it,but when I pushed it with *docker push* command the image seemed to be pushed twice,once was pushed with the tag I made,and the other time was pushed with the latest tag.And I check the images with the *docker images* command it came out as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FogWH.png)

As you can see,there are two images with the same image ID but different tags.I wonder how this happend.

Comment: See http://container-solutions.com/docker-latest-confusion/

Comment: I know why this happened.There is a “-t” param in my "docker build" command,and I used the "docker tag" command after buiding my image.

Comment: It appears you've already solved your question. If not, please include the commands and input to reproduce your issue, the results you found, and your desired results.